# java.util.logging.FileHandler - проблема перезаписи файлов

Tags: java, файлы, логирование

```
cmds = Logger.getAnonymousLogger();
File lf = new File(getDataFolder(), "commands.log");
FileHandler fh = new FileHandler(lf.getAbsolutePath(), true);
fh.setFormatter(new XSimpleFormatter("%date [%level] %msg"));
cmds.addHandler(fh);
```

И вот сама проблема - по идее должно быть два файла - **commands.log** и **commands.log.lck**, но при каждом перезапуске начинают плодиться **commands.log.0**, **commands.log.1** и так далее. Где ошибка?

UPD: log4j и прочие предлагать пока не надо. Меня *util.logging* пока устраивает во всем, кроме вышеописанной проблемы

Comment: @Barmaley, Нужно чтобы все писалось в один файл, а не создавался каждый раз новый.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет никакой ошибки, все правильно. Конструктор `FileHandler(String pattern)` где `pattern` - это **маска файлов** используемых для вывода.

Прочтите внимательно [документацию](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/logging/FileHandler.html)

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то после каждой записи лога, файл нужно закрывать fh.close()
чтобы он не лочился.